# Nifi - SSLError CertificateError - hostname 'dev.example.com' doesn't match 'nifi-node1'

Tags: docker, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi, self-signed-certificate

I'm running 3 node docker cluster on a single host lets say `dev.example.com`

I have followed https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/walkthroughs.html#creating-and-securing-a-nifi-cluster-w...  but added every node into a seperate docker container

nifi-node1 0.0.0.0:8096 -> 8080/tcp

nifi-node2 0.0.0.0:8097 -> 8080/tcp

nifi-node3 0.0.0.0:8098 -> 8080/tcp

I'm accessing using https://dev.example.com:8096/nifi . I have imported client cert on my browser, I'm able to access everything from Chrome.

I want to use python to start/stop/manipulate the processors using nipyapi

```
import os
import nipyapi

SSL_DIR = '/home/ubuntu/ssl'
nipyapi.config.nifi_config.host = 'https://dev.example.com:8096/nifi-api'

ca_file = os.path.join(SSL_DIR, 'nifi-cert.pem')
client_cert_file = os.path.join(SSL_DIR, 'CN=nifi-node1_OU=NIFI.pem')
client_key_file = os.path.join(SSL_DIR, 'CN=nifi-node1_OU=NIFI_key.pem')
client_key_password = 'Random_Password'

nipyapi.security.set_service_ssl_context(service='nifi', ca_file=ca_file, client_cert_file=client_cert_file, client_key_file=client_key_file, client_key_password=client_key_password)

nipyapi.canvas.get_root_pg_id()
```

​

I'm receiving the following error

```
WARNING:urllib3.connection:Certificate did not match expected hostname: dev.example.com. Certificate: {'subject': ((('organizationalUnitName', 'NIFI'),), (('commonName', 'nifi-node1'),)), 'issuer': ((('organizationalUnitName', 'NIFI'),), (('commonName', 'localhost'),)), 'version': 3, 'serialNumber': '017745358C8500000000', 'notBefore': 'Jan 27 18:57:53 2021 GMT', 'notAfter': 'May 2 18:57:53 2023 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'nifi-node1'),)}

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dev.example.com', port=8096): Max retries exceeded with url: /nifi-api/flow/process-groups/root/status (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'dev.example.com' doesn't match 'nifi-node1'",),))
```

Comment: The commonName or one if the altNames in the certificate must match the domain name that is used to access the url. Otherwise, the certificate is not accepted. However, that’s exactly what the error message says, so I’m not sure what you are asking?